# PHP script: download ics file

Tags: php, download, icalendar

I'm setting up a feature for "exporting as ics file" (iCal) our weekly school agenda.
The download prompt works but when opening it in iCal (Mac OS X), iCal tells me the calendar is invalid. I opened the file in a text editor and it looks ok to me.

I suspect my download.php script is wrong or setting the wrong mimetype.

I tried `text` and `text/calendar`. No luck.

So my question is this: what's the correct mimetype for ics files?

Comment: Please detail the header you use in PHP, to download the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> iCalendar data has the MIME content type text/calendar.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)

If you're saving it then loading it, I doubt that's the problem though - check your data, charset, line endings...

Comment: ok thanks. I'll create  a new question more related to the code if i can't manage it.

Answer (score 1):

```
text/calendar
```

From the [RFC 2447  iCalendar Message-Based Interoperability Protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2447.txt):

> **2.1 MIME Media Type**
>
> A MIME entity containing content
>   information formatted according to
>   this document will be referenced as a
>   "text/calendar" content type.    It is
>   assumed that this content type will be
>   transported through a    MIME
>   electronic mail transport.

Answer (score 0):

This might be handy for others its an iCal validator - http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/